# An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda

Tags: c#, .net-core, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I  am very new to AWS.
While Publish my code to Aws Serverless Lambda API. After processing of 100% it gives error of

```
Found existing stack: True
The stack's current state of UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED is invalid for updating
Failed to publish AWS Serverless application
```

and on server when checked on the server it shows

```
Description : An AWS Serverless Application that uses the ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda.
Status Reason: The following resource(s) failed to update: [AspNetCoreFunctionRole].
Status : UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED
```

Don't know what to check, where to check. I think some error of dot net version, these are the dot net related apps installed in my system.
[image]

Comment: Looks like there's something role with the IAM role (`AspNetCoreFunctionRole`) you're trying to configure as part of your CloudFormation stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was "ASP.NET Core framework running in Amazon Lambda”

1. WE have to delete this policy before publishing.
2. WE created a role to our bucket by adding two policies AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole and AWSLambda_FullAccess.

Its working fine now.